# How to find the duration of video given Mongo GridFS length?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I have a GridFS file with these data,

> ```
> "filename" : "op_1",
> "length" : NumberLong(552999),
> "chunkSize" : 512000,
> "uploadDate" : ISODate("2018-05-16T11:13:17.300Z"),
> ```

So, is there any way to get the duaration of the video file from the length value given above?

Comment: You cannot. You need to read that information from the actual file content itself. You would need to return the streams and inspect them using an appropriate library for the content format.

Comment: GridFS only stores content, and does not presume to understand what the content is. Video files adds further complexity as modern video coders are using variable rate coding, which means that the size of the file has limited correlation with the actual video length. If this is a frequent operation you need to run, I suggest you determine the video length before inserting it into GridFS and put the information in the GridFS metadata (see [files.metadata](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#files.metadata) for examples)